# Regex Pattern for Matching Single Lines of Text/Chars

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Say, for the following String, what Regex pattern would I use for matching (and returning an array of matches) for single lines of text/chars (**as in starting with characters as opposed to symbols and spaces**):

```
** Header
------------------------------------------------------------

https://www.google.com Google Homepage

Test description for Google homepage

Stack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Test description for Stack Overflow
```

... when ideally, I want an output like this from **using Google Apps Script** and `RegExp`'s `exec()` or `String`'s `match()`:

```
["https://www.google.com Google Homepage", "Test description for Google homepage", "Stack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com)", "Test description for Stack Overflow"]
```

Here's the script I have so far:

```
function testRegex() {
  var test = "** Header\n------------------------------------------------------------\n\nhttps://www.google.com Google Homepage\n\nTest description for Google homepage\n\nStack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com)\n\nTest description for Stack Overflow"
  var regExp = RegExp(".*");
  var matches = regExp.exec(test);

  for each (var match in matches) {
    Logger.log("match: " + match);
  }
}
```

... which outputs:

```
match: ** Header
match: 0
match: ** Header
------------------------------------------------------------

https://www.google.com Google Homepage

Test description for Google homepage

Stack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Test description for Stack Overflow
```

^ Notice how the matches aren't logged individually in single lines.

I've also tried a Regex pattern like `RegExp("^[a-zA-Z].*")` for only lines starting with characters, but there are no matches.

Or, would I be better off using `split()` instead? If so, I'd like to exclude lines that start with either symbols or spaces, and get an output like the one I mentioned above.

Comment: What did you try?  Take a look at [regex101.com[(https://regex101.com). if you're using regex. Are you trying to split on a newline?

Comment: Yep, I tried the website, but it can be deceiving since `.` dot notation doesn't seem to be supported in JavaScript, or at least Google Apps Script - so I've been trying out `\\s\\S` with other Regex combinations to output an array of matches from either `exec()` or `match()` functions, but to no avail. Also, I edited the question a bit btw

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: It would really help us help you if you included what you tried, and what exactly did not work as expected. What did you get vs what you expected.  There are great resources in the Help center, that explain how to write a question in a way to efficiently help us help you. Do you actually get different results if you try in a javascript REPL than you do within Google Apps ?

Comment: @Tanaike Ok, updated. Sorry about not including what I have in the first place!

Comment: Do you need to add any flags: `/g` `/m` `/u` `/i` or `/y` ?
I think JS and `/y` tripped me up in the past. For some reason a script I had needed `/y` to work as expected in JS, whereas it worked fine in php without any flags.
Also, I generally need to us the `/g` flag.  If you want it to find *all* instances rather than just stopping at the *first* match, `/g` often is needed.

Comment: Also check greedy vs non-greedy. And whether text has /n or /n/r, and if . is supposed to match newline characters. `^` may refer to the entire string, rather than the start of a line.  `/m` multiline flag: `The ^ and $ anchors now match at the beginning/end of each line respectively, instead of beginning/end of the entire string.
/^d.+\d{3}$/m
digits coming up 443`

Comment: @DaveNOTDavid Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about this? ``var res = test.split("\n").filter(String).filter(function(e){return !regExp.test(e)});`` Before you run the script, please modify ``var regExp = RegExp(".*");`` to ``var regExp = RegExp("^[*-]");``. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp If there are lines with other patterns, please show them.

Comment: @DaveNOTDavid ``var regExp = RegExp("^[*-]");`` was ``var regExp = new RegExp("^[*-]");``. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` matches a single line of text

`^[a-zA-Z].*` matches a line that begins by a letter

Comment: `.` dot notation doesn't work well with JavaScript, or at least Google Apps Script. Because of that, I've been resorting to `\s\S` with some other Regex combinations to output an array of matches using `exec()` or `match()`. Oh, and I edited the question a bit btw

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but it works.

```js
const regex = /([A-Za-z\*\:\.\s/\-\(\)]*)(\\n)/gm;
const str = `** Header\\n------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\nhttps://www.google.com Google Homepage\\n\\nTest description for Google homepage\\n\\nStack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com)\\n\\nTest description for Stack Overflow`;
const subst = `$1\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[See and modify this script on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KEqCMn/1)

It seems `split` might be more straight forward, but I assume you tried that before posting, and Q was tagged with regex.
Also, I suspect the above regex may be able to be greatly simplified.